# Calling a MVC Controller From a PartiaView with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call a method on the controller from a partial view. I am able to send an alert from the jquery with the correct values but the method does not execute. I've tried several different jquery calls but this is the latest and it still does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult AssignedContacts(int id)
{
    CarrierCode item = model.CarrierCodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    return PartialView(item);
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carrier-codes-table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
        var codeId = $td.eq(0).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AssignedContacts")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: codeId }),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#assigned-contacts').empty().load(data);
            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue here is probably with the Razor Url helper. Check your debug network monitor -- What url is the browser attempting to use? Is your javascript on a view page or in a separate _js_ file?

Comment: Try changing `$('#assigned-contacts').empty().load(data);` to `$('#assigned-contacts').html(data);`

Comment: You are correct. I should have checked that. The jquery is on the page right now. Here is the url call - GET /CarrierRouteAssignments/AssignedContacts?{"id":"\n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20\n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201\n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20\n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"}&_=1

Comment: Instead of `data: JSON.stringify({ id: codeId }),` it should be `data: { id: codeId }),`

Comment: Got it!. I changed $td.eq(0).text() to $td.eq(0).text().trim().

Answer (score 0):

I got a quick sample to work with the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#carrier-codes-table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
        var codeId = $td.eq(0).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/AssignedContracts',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: { id: codeId },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#assigned-contacts').empty().html(data);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I found the problem in the $td.eq(0).text() results. I added a trim() to it and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!. I changed $td.eq(0).text() to $td.eq(0).text().trim().

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#carrier-codes-table').on('click', 'tbody tr', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
    var codeId = $td.eq(0).text().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AssignedContacts")',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: {id: codeId },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#assigned-contacts').html(data);
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
 });
});
```